# Distinct count Comma separated values in column excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, distinct-values

How can i distinct count values in a column where inside each row cell i could have more than one values separated with comma like this table:

I have a solution if a split the table but can i use one function that does this on the fly?
so no temp tables etc...?

[image]

Comment: Can the same value appear more than once in a cell (ex.: `French, English, French`)?

Comment: On average, how many languages total can we expect? 20,30,1000?  Not unique, total.

Comment: 200 languages i expect Scott and cybernetic it may (thought it shouldn't)

Comment: You think it shouldn't or or you are sure it won't?

Comment: it shouldn't but it is possibility so yes we should expect same language twice in row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume input data housed in `A1:A14` with header

[image]

1] For Distinct language list

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",1,A$2:A$14),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[not(preceding::*=.)]["&ROW(A1)&"]"),"")
```

Edit :

2] For distinct count

In `B2` :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+ISTEXT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",1,A$2:A$14),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[not(preceding::*=.)]")))
```

[image]

The formula using TEXTJOIN function which is available in Office365 or Excel2019, and FILTERXML function which is available in Excel2013

Comment: @kyrpav what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @kyrpav, do you have Office 365 or Excel2019? I have tested it in my Excel 2019 worksheet and it is work for me as per screenshot.

Comment: office 365 is my version, and somehow it started needing commas instead of semicolumns, i did restart it wait a moment

Comment: @kyrpav that is the local setting of the computer not Excel.

Comment: yes i know i checked , it was ok, the problem was just in excel it needed only to restart

Comment: It works perfectly, but can you also explain to me the logic, cause i did not understood it? cause i want to expand it in order to calculate specific part of the column based on filter from user. So i want to understand this in order to expand it

Comment: @kyrpav, If you want to learn how XML and Xpath work in FILTERXML function, please check these pages in https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp